# What is this fuse socket in my 1988 Toyota Corolla?

Tags: toyota, battery, corolla

[image][image]

What is this it's attached to my positive terminal and had both of these in it which one goes where and am I missing any?

Answer (score 1):

Those are fuses or fusible links.

Can’t tell from the photo which one will go where, but can see 60A and 30A.

Edit to 60 & 30 based in comment.
If you can see the wires - and one pair is thicker than the other, then put the 60A on the thicker ones.

Comment: I think the second one is a 30A.